# Плохая скорость выполнения кода java

Tags: java

Написанный код оказался невероятно медленным по сравнению с подобными на других языках. Дело в самом коде или же проблема в чём-то другом?

```java
private void DictEntry(int numOfCh) throws IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите имя файла: ");
    String filename = input.nextLine() + ".txt";

    int maxNumber = (int) Math.pow(10, numOfCh);
    int numThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename))) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            final int threadId = i;
            threads[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    for (int j = threadId; j < maxNumber; j += numThreads) {
                        writer.write(String.format("%0" + numOfCh + "d%n", j));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка при записи в файл: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            threads[i].start();
        }
            
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка при ожидании завершения потока: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка при создании файла: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    System.out.println("Словарь " + filename + " был успешно создан");
}
```

Comment: А какой смысл данного кода?  И с какими именно другими _невероятно быстрыми_ языками выполняется сравнение?

Comment: Писать параллельно в файлы - затея провальная на всех языках...

Comment: В один и тот же файл, через синхронизировнный `BufferedWriter`, с использованием форматированного вывода, и построением строки формата с помощью конкатенации )

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Научись писать быстрый код, а то говорить что код медленный, без всяких оснований.